# Usage of QVariants in C++ and Properties in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

When I write a new component for QML in C++, I use the macro:

```
Q_PROPERTY(type READ getter WRITE setter NOTIFY signal)
```

Here I might use different *type*s, e.g. `int` or `QVariant`. I was wondering, if I have any benefit of not using `QVariant` here.

[To quote the documentation:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)

> Without QVariant, this would be a problem for QObject::property() and for database work, etc.

So - what happens if I read or write to a property on the QML side?
My guess is, that it calls:

```
QVariant QObject::property(const char *name) const
bool QObject::setProperty(const char *name, const QVariant &value)
```

which means, that my properties, neatly defined as `int, dobule, QString, ...` returned by my getter will be wrapped as `QVariant` to be transferred from C++ to QML - a process that would be unnecessary if I would have defined it as `QVariant` from the beginning.

If I have a Component in QML it is very likely that I have bindings from one property to multiple other properties, so reading happens quite often. So it would be a good idea to have the type in `Q_PROPERTY` QVariant, as otherwise I would wrap it tons of times.

On the C++-Side I might decide, whether it is read often. If so, I buffer the value in the original data type for access within C++ but create the `QVariant` when ever the value changes, so for QML it is unnecessary to create it multiple times. - *Or is this happening automatically? Does a QML Object has all it's property values buffered as QVariant?*

Comment: I fail to see the thought process that gets you from that line of documentation to your following presumptions. Why not try using variants, run a test and see if it is more efficient.

Comment: Because I suck at profiling ;-) And I hope there might be someone out there, that could tell me what the marco is doing and how the MetaObjects are working. Because I think everything boils down to those?

Comment: It is more likely to get an answer on the mailing lists than here.

Comment: That might be true. If I wont get a answer here, I will ask at the QtWS or the mailing list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed some analysis and experiments on QML that lead me to this answer, which I deem very probable:

1. Experiment: Add a property `property var test` to an object, and analyze its meta object in C++. What I found is:
   The `QMetaObject::property()` method always returns a `QVariant` as described in the signature of this method, but the type of the `QVariant` is always set to the type of the property. This means a `property int someInt` results in a `QVariant::int` while a `property var someVar` results in a `QVariant::QVariant` - which means at least here, we have to unpack the value twice. **+1 for using the best fitting property type!**
2. Experiment: Add breakpoints to the source file of `QVariant` (`QtCore/qvariant.h`) at the line containing `inline QVariant(QVariant &&other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : d(other.d)` and `inline QVariant &operator=(QVariant &&other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW`, which I found likely to be called when I change the value of a `QVariant` in QML.
   In QML I added a `Button` which incremented its `x` position upon click.
   As expected, when ever I clicked the Button, those two lines were called repeatedly. Unfortunately, I am missing the insight, which `QVariant`s where changed, and whether one of them is indeed our property for the position. However I don't think that Qt will have tons of `QVariant`s somewhere in the backend, so **I deem it likely, that my assumption is true, and on the QML-side the properties are handled as QVariant.**

---

> **Take home message:** Though the properties in QML are handled as `QVariant` it is beneficial to declare the properties using a better fitting type, as otherwise the result is not a `QVariant::int` but maybe a `QVariant::QVariant::int`.

---

In my experiments I found no trace of `QJSValues` flying around which I would not have been surprised to find instead of `QVariant::QVariant` when having a `property var ...`

Answer (score 1):

No, i think you don't. At least if you expose it to QML or use in any kind of subclasses from `QAbstractListModel`( all values there returned by data function and return type is `QVariant`)

I have just run my app throught debugger with breakpoints to see what happens with Q_`PROPERTY` variables. Just added simple code snipped in `MouseArray onClicked` function:

```
var p = ExContact.phone;
var e = ExContact.status;
```

phone is `QString` and status is `qint8` 
Going throught breakpoints shows:

1. p is undefined
2. p becomes `string`
3. p value is assigned
4. e is undefined
5. e becomes type `number`
6. e value is assigned

Calls trace is complicated in view but I can see what the QVariant is used and QMetaType is used.

So it looks like any type exposed throught Q_PROPERTY becomes QVariant anyway..

Comment: In your answer you assign the values retrieved from the property to a `QJSValue (var)`. What I was wondering, is if I have something like: `property int myNumber: fromCpp.num1 + fromCpp.num2` the values `fromCpp.num1` and ` fromCpp.num2` are transformed into `QVariant`s to get them to QML and handled there as `number` etc.

Comment: Tested:
property int test: 0

test = ExContact.phone (QString)

Error: Cannot assign QString to int 

But in Debuger in Object explorer I see whta test is an of type number and there is signal called testChanged, looks like property int is still QJSValue :/